# how to implement a truly serverless oauth

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth

Is there a way to authenticate using Oauth 2 with a web service without needing *any* support from a server? i.e., I want the exchange of auth code and auth token to happen purely between the user's browser and the web service, *without* involving any other server.

I have a javascript client running inside a web browser that needs to authenticate with a web service (such as dropbox or google)  using Oauth.

Since the access token or code being returned by the web service after authentication is in the form of a redirect, it necessarily must go to the server pointed to by the redirect_uri. On a desktop client, I can set the redirect uri to `http://localhost:3000` and pick up the response from the web service.

When the client is a javascript script running inside a browser, I cannot open a server on localhost:3000, leaving me to depend on another server on the internet for retrieving the code or token.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'password' grant type in Oauth2, which can be used without the need of the redirect uri.

It is described here: https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#others

But the downside is that client app needs to know the username and password, so it might no be suitable in all cases.